# How can I sort an array that dependes on the quantity of other?

Tags: c, arrays, graph, qsort

For Example I have this array:

```c
G->colour = [2,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,2];
G->vertex = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
G->order = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]; //the same of vertex
```

vertex 1 has colour 2, vertex 2 has colour 1, etc...
I need this solution `G->order = [1,9,3,5,7,2,4,6,8]`.  I want to sort order using the number of vertex with same colour in growing order, i.e.,

- I have two vertex with colour 2 (vertexes: 1, 9)
- I have three vertex with colour 0 (vertexes: 3,5,7)
- I have four vertex with colour 1 (vertexes : 2,4,6,8)

I have a function (RMBC) that sorts vertexes by colour. For example:

```c
G->colour = [2,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,2];
G->order = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
```

This returns the function `order = [3,5,7,2,4,6,8,1,9]`.

Besides I put the graph struct, and the greedy function that colours our vertexes.

I have much more code but I think that with this is okey.

Thanks!

```c
typedef struct Graph
{
    u32** vecinos;
    u32* vertexes;  // Position of vertexes
    u32* color; //Structure type declarations do not support initializers
    u32* grados;
    u32* order; //it has the order of vertex for greedy
    u32* visitados;
    u32 m; //number of edges
    u32 n; // number of vertex
    u32 max; // number of colors
    u32* indEnVecinos;
} Graph;

//RMBC
u32* vert_color;
char RMBC(Graph* G)
{
    vert_color = G->color;
    qsort(G->order, G->n, sizeof(u32), compColoresNormal);
    return 0;
}

int compColoresNormal(const void *v1, const void *v2) {
    u32 color1 = vert_color[*(const u32 *)v1 - 1];
    u32 color2 = vert_color[*(const u32 *)v2 - 1];
    if (color1 < color2)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (color1 > color2)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
// end RMBC

//Greedy 
u32 Greedy(Graph* G)
{
    u32** aux = G->vecinos; 
    u32 max_color = 0;
    u32 nVer = G->n;
    u32* color_vecinos = (u32*)malloc(sizeof(u32) * nVer);
    memset(color_vecinos,0,nVer*sizeof(u32));
    u32 indice = binarySearch(G->vertexes,0,nVer-1,G->order[0]);
    G->color[indice] = 0;
    G->visitados[indice] = 1;
    u32 indice2 = 0;
    u32 reset = 0; 
    for (u32 i = 1; i < nVer; ++i)
    {
        memset(color_vecinos,0,(reset+1)*sizeof(u32));
        indice = binarySearch(G->vertexes,0,nVer-1,G->order[i]);
        G->visitados[indice] = 1;
        u32 color = 0;
        reset = 0;
        for (u32 i = 0; i < G->grados[indice]; ++i)
        {
            indice2 = binarySearch(G->vertexes,0,nVer-1,aux[G->indEnVecinos[indice]+i][1]);
            if(G->visitados[indice2])
            {
                color_vecinos[G->color[indice2]] = 1;
                if(reset < G->color[indice2]) reset = G->color[indice2];
            }
        }
        for (u32 i = 0; i < nVer; ++i)
        {
            if(!color_vecinos[i])
            {
                color = i; 
                break;
            }
        }
        G->color[indice] = color;
        if(color > max_color) max_color = color;
        if(reset < color) reset = color;
        if(reset == nVer) reset--;
    }
    free(color_vecinos);
    printf("terminé Greedy\n");
    return max_color + 1;
}
//end Greedy
```

Comment: What is your question (which array do you need to sort)?

Comment: Hi @bearaqua, I need to sort order array

Comment: it is more to _make_ the array _order_ from the array _color_ and _vertex_. Is _vertex_  always contains 1,2,3 ... ? or if _vertex_ is 9,8,... that means vertex 9 has color 2 etc ?

Comment: @Marcos Cerioni How much extra space can you use? If you use bucketting (extra O(n)) space then everything is quite trivial.

Comment: Hi @bruno, the vertex array can have 9, 8, etc. Is like vertex array is the name of the vertex, and that name is a unsigned int. So ```G->vertex = [9,100,58888,2], 
G->colur = [0,1,0,2]```. And that means that vertex 9 has colour 0, vertex 100 has colour 1, etc

Answer (score 1):

Are your colors and vertexes *small* numbers?

Encode the pair into a single number, sort, and decode

```
//G->colour = [2,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,2];
//G->vertex = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

colour * 1000 + vertex // based on small values!!

// encode to
// [2001, 1002, 3, 1004, 5, 1006, 7, 1008, 2009]
// sort to
// [2001, 2009, 3, 5, 7, 1002, 1004, 1006, 1008]
// decode to
//G->colour = [2,2,0,0,0,1,1,1,1];
//G->vertex = [1,9,3,5,7,2,4,6,8];
```

Comment: Hi @pmg. No, Ihave very big numers. I use unsigned int for everything

Comment: A more robust approach (as to a fixed `1000`) is to scan through the `vertex` array, record the maximum value, and scale the factor accordingly.

Comment: @prng For very large numbers you just need to turn your approach into an array-based approach, but the idea stays the same.

Comment: Hi @beraqua, can you help me with that? I don't know how to do it. I need a function like RMBCnew(Graph* G) that do this.

Answer (score 0):

You know what the orders already are, they're those pointed to by `v1` and `v2` - store them into a variable and then:

```
int compColoresNormal(const void *v1, const void *v2) {
    u32 order1 = *(const u32 *)v1;
    u32 order2 = *(const u32 *)v2;
    u32 color1 = vert_color[order1 - 1];
    u32 color2 = vert_color[order2 - 1];
    if (color1 < color2) {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (color1 > color2) {
        return 1;
    }
    // same color, use the order
    else {
        // return 0;
        // branchless comparison expression
        return (order2 < order1) - (order1 < order2);
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean only `return (order2 < order1) - (order1 < order2);` without two `if`s before ... and the question is not about _compColoresNormal_ ;-)